# colored array of output

Tags: output-formatting, color

I would like to have colored array of an output.
Assume for example we have an array of numbers or texts as output and we want different colors for different classes of them. For example

> > A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

and we want **Odd** numbers be **Blue** and **Even** numbers be **Red**.

or

> > PrimeQ[A]
> >     which gives **True** or **False**, with **Blue** color for **True** and **Red** color for False.

Thanks.

Comment: `ArrayPlot[{A}, ColorFunction -> (If[EvenQ[#], Red, Blue] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]` or `ArrayPlot[{A}, ColorFunction -> (If[PrimeQ[#], Red, Blue] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`

Comment: Or even shorter, `ArrayPlot[{A}, ColorRules -> {_?EvenQ -> Red, _ -> Blue}]`

Comment: `Replace[A, {n_?EvenQ :> Style[n, Red], n_ :> Style[n, Blue]}, {1}]` or more generally `MakeBoxes[n_?EvenQ, StandardForm] := StyleBox[n, Red];
MakeBoxes[n_?OddQ, StandardForm] := StyleBox[n, Blue]`

Comment: @Xavier, thanks, I need some output as your first command, but it does not work for other functions such "PrimeQ".

Comment: @asad It seems that `Replace[A, {n_?PrimeQ :> Style[n, Blue], n_ :> Style[n, Red]}, {1}]` does what you want, isn't it the case?

Comment: @Xavier, thanks, it did!

Answer (score 2):

**First approach**

Function to change the style of elements of a specific class in an expression.

*Code.*

```
SetAttributes[coloredreplace, HoldAllComplete];

coloredreplace[expr_, testQ_, colors: {True -> c1_?ColorQ, False -> c2_?ColorQ}] := 
    coloredreplace[expr, {Sequence[], testQ}, colors];

coloredreplace[expr_, {head_, testQ_}, {True -> c1_?ColorQ, False -> c2_?ColorQ}] := 
    Replace[expr, {n_head?testQ :> Style[n, c1], n_head :> Style[n, c2]}, {1}];
```

*Usage.*

*1)* For `EvenQ` elements:

```
expr1 = Range[8];

coloredreplace[expr1, EvenQ, {True -> Red, False -> Blue}]
```

[image]

```
% === coloredreplace[expr1, {Integer, EvenQ}, {True -> Red, False -> Blue}]
(* True *)
```

*2)* For `PrimeQ` elements:

```
coloredreplace[expr1, {Integer, PrimeQ}, {True -> Blue, False -> Red}]
```

[image]

*3)* For elements satisfying a `StringMatchQ` test:

```
expr2 = {"a", "1", 1, "b", "2", 2, "c", "3", 3};

coloredreplace[expr2, StringMatchQ[#, LetterCharacter] &, {True -> Red, False -> Blue}]
```

[image]

We can specify the head to get a cleaner pattern:

```
coloredreplace[expr2, {String, StringMatchQ[#, LetterCharacter] &}, 
                      {True -> Red, False -> Blue}
]
```

[image]

This removed the messages and changed the display for non-`String` elements.

**Second approach**

Function to define global rules of display for elements of a specific class.

*Code.*

```
coloreddisplay[{head_, testQ_}, {True -> c1_?ColorQ, False -> c2_?ColorQ}] :=
    Module[{},

        FormatValues[MakeBoxes] = DeleteCases[FormatValues[MakeBoxes],
            HoldPattern[
                Verbatim[HoldPattern][MakeBoxes[
                   Verbatim[PatternTest][Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[Blank][head]], _], 
                   StandardForm
                ]] :> 
                RowBox[{StyleBox[_, color_]}]
            ] /; ColorQ[color]
        ];

        MakeBoxes[n_head?testQ, StandardForm] := RowBox[{StyleBox[n, c1]}];
        MakeBoxes[n_head, StandardForm] := RowBox[{StyleBox[n, c2]}];

    ];
```

*Usage.*

```
coloreddisplay[{Integer, EvenQ}, {True -> Red, False -> Blue}];

expr1
```

[image]

```
coloreddisplay[{Integer, PrimeQ}, {True -> Blue, False -> Red}];

expr1
```

[image]

```
coloreddisplay[{String, StringMatchQ[#, LetterCharacter] &}, {True -> Red, False -> Blue}]

expr2
```

[image]

The digits `1`, `2` and `3` are colored because the rule for `PrimeQ` elements define previously still applies. Removing all rules generated by `coloreddisplay` can be simply done with `FormatValues[MakeBoxes] = {}`, which could be written in its code instead of the `DeleteCases` part if needed. Note that this will also delete `MakeBoxes` rules defined elsewhere.