# Color numbers based on their value

Tags: color

Given some number between 0 and 1:

```
RandomReal[1, 100]
```

I'm trying to color the values based on their size. I tried it like this:

```
numbersColored = 
 Table[Style[numbers[[x]], Darker[Red, 1 - numbers[[x]]]], {x, 1, 
   Length@numbers}]
```

which uses red and `Darker`. I was wondering, however, if there is a more elegant way (without using `Table` for example) of doing this that also lets me choose some color function?

Comment: This isn't really any different than your code, just using `Map` instead of `Table`:  `style = Style[#, Darker[Red, 1 - #]] &;
style /@ numbers`

Comment: In my opinion, a more readable `Table` version would be `Table[Style[n, Darker[Red, 1-n]], {n, numbers}]`

Comment: Jason B.'s (pruned) is elegant too:  `Style[#,Darker[Red,1-#]]& /@ numbers` (and doesn't use `Table`)

Comment: Thanks for these solutions! But how about using some sort of color function instead of one single color? I wasn't able to figure this out yet ;)

Comment: @holistic you can use any color function, like `Style[#, Hue[#]] & /@ numbers` or `Style[#, ColorData["Rainbow"][#]] & /@ numbers`

Comment: Thanks all for the nice solutions, could learn some stuff :)

Comment: Tangentially related, you might find interest in [(127062)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127062/121) and the questions in the **Linked** sidebar on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Style[#, ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[Round[10 #]]]] & /@ numbers
```

Comment: Thank you David!