# How can we change the Highlighted elements to a specific color?

Tags: color, syntax-highlighting

**edit** I don't want highlighting, only font color. Sorry.
I want the `Highlighted` elements to be Blue Font. I can't understand [this suggested previous post.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121118/973)

When I try to replace `Highlighted` with a `Style`, it doesn't change the list $r.$ Can you help?

```
Clear[m, n, s];
odd[n_] := 2 n - 1
SoEScratchPad[n_] := Boole[PrimeQ[odd[n]]]*odd[n]
s = Array[SoEScratchPad, 200];
rowSums[n_] := Module[{r = s[[1 ;; n]] + Reverse[s[[1 ;; n]]]},
Do[If[r[[m]] == 0 || OddQ[r[[m]]], 
  r[[m]] = Highlighted[r[[m]]]], {m, 1, Length[r]}]; r]
Array[rowSums, 20] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Try `Highlighted[Style[r[[m]], Blue]]`.

Comment: change `Highlighted[r[[m]]]` to  `Highlighted[r[[m]], BaseStyle -> Blue]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Highlighted[r[[m]]]` to

```
Style[r[[m]], 16, Blue, Bold]]
```

[image]

If you need the yellowish background, you can change `Highlighted[r[[m]]]` in your code to

```
 Highlighted[r[[m]], BaseStyle -> Directive[16, Blue, Bold]]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Or `Highlighted[Style[r[[m]], Blue, Bold]]]`.

Comment: The is good if we can get rid of the yellow.

Comment: Remove the `Highlighted`, just use `Style[r[[m]], Blue, Bold]`. Or `Highlighted[Style[r[[m]], Blue, Bold], Background -> White]`.